How do I properly include an AAR dependency in another library?
I'm having to build a .aar file for use in Unity. I'm porting over functionality from exist .java files we utilize in Unreal Engine.
However, our code depends on another provided .aar file, to which we do not have the source to.
I am working in Android Studio 2022.3.1, and the modules are using kotlin style gradle files.
I've followed everything I can find online, but currently I'm using the steps of creating a new module, adding the .aar to the libs folder and including this module project as a dependency. That, however, does not seem to force the inclusion of the .aar dependency.
Here is the gradle.kts file for the module created to house the .aar file.
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.pixovr.tobservicelib"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 29

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}

And here is the gradle.kts file for the module that has the dependency.
    id("com.android.library")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.pixovr.pico_installer"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 29

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags("")
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path("src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt")
            version = "3.22.1"
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    implementation(project(":tobservicelib"))
}```

I expected this to resolve my dependency issue but the import statements still don't know what it's looking for, despite knowing that they are the correct import statements.

If there is a way to either fix this solution or a different solution I should take, all help is appreciated.


Related: Error building Android library: Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported
